# Lidar shows very few points. RPLIDAR A2M8

Tags: ros2, slam, amcl, lidar

I'm using an RPLidar A2 for Slam on my robot but after mapping, when I am trying to localise, the lidar shows very few points. Is this normal? This lidar supposedly has a 12m range. Because it sees very few points, AMCL is having a hard time localising.
Any help would be appereciated! I'm running out of time :(

Have a look at the map vs the actual live /scan data:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Crab00189. Where are you seeing that it has a range of 12 meters? When I look at the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/e/a/f/9/8/LD208_SLAMTEC_rplidar_datasheet_A2M8_v1.0_en.pdf) (warning: Direct PDF download) from [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/14756), the datasheet says it's an 8 meter range, and that is also 8 meters to a 70% reflectivity surface, which is quite high. The SparkFun site states 12 meters, but that's not what the manufacturer states. How is it mounted on the robot? It could be hitting vehicle structure below the minimum range.

Comment: Thanks Chuck. I read it here: https://wiki.slamtec.com/display/SD/Overseas+Help+Center?preview=/83066883/83066891/LD208_SLAMTEC_rplidar_datasheet_A2M8_v2.6_en.pdf . I’m not sure why some places say 6m while some say 12m for the exact same A2M8 :(. It’s mounted at the top, nothing is around it.